# Creating a product managment project that allows the user to choose between creating a product, search for one or exit the program

Tags: c#, dictionary, console, key-value, product-management

Im facing a problem with searching for a product concept, i have succeded with making it possible to create a product, and giving a warning message if the user tried to create a product with the same articleId.

But if i create more than one product, and search for a specifc one im getiing the information of all the created product in the dictionary.

Here im declaring a dictionary with both type int and string

```
Dictionary<int, string> products = new Dictionary<int, string>();

bool applicationRunning = true;

Console.CursorVisible = false;
```

and here is the menu

```
 do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till FreakyFashion, välj ett alternativ nedan!");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("(1) Ny produkt");
        Console.WriteLine("(2) Sök produkt");
        Console.WriteLine("(3) Avsluta");

    ConsoleKeyInfo userInput;

    bool invalidSelection = true;

    do
    {
        userInput = Console.ReadKey(true);

        invalidSelection = !(
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.D1 ||
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1 ||
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.D2 ||
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2 ||
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.D3 ||
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad3
            );

    } while (invalidSelection);

    Console.Clear();
    Console.CursorVisible = true;
```

And as you could see here, this where the user writes down the information of the product that is going to be created

```
    switch (userInput.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D1:
        case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
            Console.Write("Artikelnummer: ");
            int articleId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Namn: ");
            string nameOfProduct = (Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Clear();
```

Here im showing the user what he gave for a name for the product and what he gave for a number for articleId, and im also asking the user if the information is correct then press 'J' to save the information in dictionary, otherwise press 'N' to start over

```
            Console.WriteLine(("Namn: ") + nameOfProduct + ("\n Artikelnummer: ") + articleId + "\n Stämmer detta? (J)a (N)ej");
            //Console.ReadKey(true);
            //products.Add(articleId, nameOfProduct);


            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;



            if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.J) && products.ContainsKey(articleId))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Artikelnummer är redan registerad");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                break;
            }
            else if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.N))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;
            }
            else if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.J))
            {
                products.Add(articleId, nameOfProduct);

                Console.WriteLine("Produkten Registerat");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.Clear();
                break;

            }

            break;
```

Here is when im facing the problem, if the user for example created three diffrent products with three diffrent names and id's, and the user searched for one specific product, the program for som reason givs the information of every singel product the user created even if the user did not search for it

```
        case ConsoleKey.D2:
        case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:

            Console.Write("Ange produkt namn: ");

            nameOfProduct = Console.ReadLine();

             if (products.ContainsValue(nameOfProduct))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> s in products)
                    Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + s.Value + "\n" + "Artikelnummer: " + s.Key);
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }




            break;
```

We can exit the program here

```
        case ConsoleKey.D3:
        case ConsoleKey.NumPad3:

            applicationRunning = false;

            break;
    }

    Console.Clear();

} while (applicationRunning);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this block:

```
        if (products.ContainsValue(nameOfProduct))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> s in products)
                Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + s.Value + "\n" + "Artikelnummer: " + s.Key);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
```

If your condition is true then it goes to a `foreach` loop and just writes all items from `products` dictionary. To solve this you can add additional condition: `products.Where(product => product.Value.Equals(nameOfProduct))`
or rewrite full block like the following:

```
var searched = products.Where(product => product.Value.Equals(nameOfProduct)).ToList();
if(searched.Any())
{ 
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> s in searched)
            Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + s.Value + "\n" + "Artikelnummer: " + s.Key);
        Console.ReadKey(true);

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the user input case insensitive?

Comment: @MalekMshensh yes, Equals method has [several method overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#case-insensitive-ordinal-comparisons)